# Flash CS6 swiffy option don't show

Tags: flash, command, directory, google-swiffy

I got flash cs6 and tried to install the swiffy plugin to convert a file.
But the 'export to html5' option doesn't appear in my "commands" panel.

I tried the solution proposed, 'manage extension', but it says swiffy is properly installed and enabled. I tried deactivate/reactivate and even reinstall it, but nothing changes : it works fine in extension manager, and don't appear in CS6 'commands' menu. (or elsewhere)

I tried to find where do Swiffy install files, checking on langage folders and all (as the basic solution implies it has something to do with langage mix-up), but can't find anything relevant.

As I had problems with langages at my first install of CS6 years ago, maybe I didn't properly uninstall/reinstall/install stuff around, and swiffy got lost into a langage folder that isn't the active one when in CS6. (my best guess)

Anyone have more info on what files (or assimilate) swiffy install and where ?
Or on where are the known 'langage-related' folders for Flash CS6, so I can check them and try to find the problem ?
Or how to manually insert an additionnal command to make swiffy appear 'the brutal way' in my Flash interface ?
Any workaround regarding CS6 plugin ?

Thanks a lot, I've spent the whole day on that, I'm bald, now, from pulling so much hair trying to find any info.

Comment: On Windows 7, I found Swiffy.xmp (and .mxi and .mxi_air) in C:\Users\**me**\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Extension Manager CS6\EM Store\Flash CS6

Answer (score 0):

Thx, plugincontainer!

For those searching the solution : 
"... AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Extension Manager CS6\EM Store\Flash CS6"
This location lead to swiffy install files.

Opening those with notepad, I found out swiffy install 3 files, located there :

C:\Users\ **me**\AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CS6\en_US\Configuration\External Libraries\Swiffy.dll

C:\Users\ **me**\AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CS6\en_US\Configuration\Commands\Export as HTML5 (Swiffy).jsfl

C:\Users\ **me**\AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CS6\en_US\Configuration\Extensions\SWIFFY_LICENSE.TXT

(replace " **me**" by proper values)
Copy/pasting those into the proper langage sub-directory and restarting Flash CS6 fixed my problem!